# Dynamic Group Lookup in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

I have been experimenting with different ways of doing dynamic Actor and Group lookup. I am currently implementing a custom UserGroupCallback. My authorization is tricky since it does not conform to the standard JAAS model. Each user has a role (Assistant, Administrator, Officer); however, that role is for a specific department and functionality for that department. For example, someone can be an assistant in the HR department, but they only have permission to use time keeping functionality.

In my initial experiment, I created a Service task which had inputs for role, department, and functionality permissions. I would then perform a lookup to determine which users meet the criteria and would return a comma separated String with all the users. I would save that string as a process variable and set the Actor list for my User Task to #{ApprovedUsers}. This approach works, but I dislike having a predefined user list since role permissions could change by the time the task is acted upon.

The next logical step was to the generating a dynamic comma separated list of group ids. Since a group needs to be a single string, I concatenated all of the possible attributes with the role. Using the previous example, the user's role would become 'assistant_hr_timekeeping'. I was able to get this to work,  but as I started to go down this path, I noticed that the number of groups started to get out of hand. Additionally there are multiple users that have multiple or 'ALL' for their department and/or functionality. The main reason I didn't want to go down this route was that it is likely that we will need to add more permissions in the future, which would break all of the processes that are created prior to the switch over.

I have a solution that works, but it is very kludgey and not easy to update for future changes. Is there something in JBPM that would allow for easier dynamic authorization of actor/groups for User Tasks? Preferably something that can be implemented in Java so that it is easier to integrate with our Authentication/Authorization system.